# Does nesting FlatList inside ScrollView hinder it's performance?

Tags: react-native

I've got following layout setup:

```
<ScrollView>
   <MyCustomView />
   <FlatList />
</ScrollView>
```

At the moment it is working as I intended it to work i.e. user scrolls past a custom view and then hits flat list with many items in it and can continue scrolling down.

My concern is that such layout is not what FlatList is intended for i.e. will it still only render items as they are needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I don't think it would create much of problem here.

As Flatlist too is an kind of scrollview so it won't cause much issue over here.

Also it would be a better approach if you keep that under flatlist and fix the view you have to hit using stickyIndices which you can get in flatlist and without comprising any rendering issues or performance hitches.

```
<FlatList
  data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
  ItemSeparatorComponent={ this.FlatListItemSeparator}
  renderItem={ ({item}) => (
    <Text
      style={styles.FlatList_Item}
      onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)}> {item.key}
      </Text>
  )}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.Render_FlatList_Sticky_header}
  stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flat list inside scroll view create some kind of performance issue so for solving this you need to take care of some things for more info refer to link below

https://medium.com/sanjagh/how-to-optimize-your-react-native-flatlist-946490c8c49b